# Does the calculation of error bars in lme4 require the Cosineau (2005) correction?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, standard-error, lme4-nlme

In Cosineau (2005) a method for calculating within-subject design error bars which removes the between subjects variance before calculating confidence intervals, error bars and so on is suggested. I was wondering if the same has to be done in linear mixed effects model as in the `lme4` package in `R` and if not why not.

Comment: Cousineau, D. (2005). Confidence intervals in within-subject designs: A simpler solution to Loftus and Masson’s method. Tutorials in Quantitative Methods for Psychology, 1(1), 42-45.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `lme4` doesn't have any plotting methods at all that purport to show group means and their error bars; thus it doesn't have any methods to which these methods would be applicable [as least as far as I understand them from briefly skimming the paper].  You would probably get similar results to those produced by Cousineau/Loftus and Masson if you calculated predicted values for each group and used the error-propagation techniques described in the [GLMM FAQ](http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html) to generate standard errors on the predictions, ignoring the uncertainties of the random effects.

It would be an interesting exercise to actually try this, but I'm going to forgo the pleasure for right now.  Cousineau doesn't give the (simulated) values underlying their figures, but it wouldn't be too hard to generate some.